# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'yard'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04, sidekiq, upstart

I am using sidekiq upstart job but while running `sudo service sidekiq restart` getting the following error

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'yard'.
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/myapp/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:231:in `require'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:231:in `boot_system'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:49:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/gems/sidekiq-3.2.5/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

Following is the upstart job

> /etc/init/sidekiq.conf

```
# /etc/init/sidekiq.conf - Sidekiq config

# This example config should work with Ubuntu 12.04+.  It
# allows you to manage multiple Sidekiq instances with
# Upstart, Ubuntu's native service management tool.
#
# See workers.conf for how to manage all Sidekiq instances at once.
#
# Save this config as /etc/init/sidekiq.conf then manage sidekiq with:
#   sudo start sidekiq index=0
#   sudo stop sidekiq index=0
#   sudo status sidekiq index=0
#
# Hack Upstart's reload command to 'quiet' Sidekiq:
#
#   sudo reload sidekiq index=0
#
# or use the service command:
#   sudo service sidekiq {start,stop,restart,status}
#

description "Sidekiq Background Worker"

# This script is not meant to start on bootup, workers.conf
# will start all sidekiq instances explicitly when it starts.
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

# change to match your deployment user
 setuid ubuntu
 setgid ubuntu


#respawn
#respawn limit 3 30

# TERM is sent by sidekiqctl when stopping sidekiq. Without declaring these as
# normal exit codes, it just respawns.
normal exit 0 TERM

# Older versions of Upstart might not support the reload command and need
# this commented out.
reload signal USR1

# Upstart waits 5 seconds by default to kill the a process. Increase timeout to
# give sidekiq process enough time to exit.
kill timeout 15

#instance $index

script
# this script runs in /bin/sh by default
# respawn as bash so we can source in rbenv
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  # Pick your poison :) Or none if you're using a system wide installed Ruby.

  source /home/ubuntu/.bash_profile
  source /home/ubuntu/.rvm/scripts/rvm
  source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
  # Logs out to /var/log/upstart/sidekiq.log by default

  cd /home/ubuntu/myapp/
  exec bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -e production
EOT
end script
```

How to get this working. I had also installed the gem `yard` but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the issue, the `$HOME` variable was not considered defined in the upstart job. So the `~` sign in `yard.rb` file of gem was not getting expanded to actual path. Than I explicitly define the variable in the upstart and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't listed `yard` in your Gemfile and done a `bundle`.

Comment: Though I haven't listed it in Gemfile but I did installed it manually. Moreover, the same Gemfile and configuration is working on other server.

Comment: I have the gem in the Gemfile and it is installed but still giving the same error